# getting the value of dropdownlist as a string ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("jenisBarang", new SelectList(ViewBag.listJenis), "Pilih Perangkat/Layanan", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlJenis", @onchange = "GetMerk(this.value);", @name="jenisBarang" })
@Html.DropDownList("merkBarang", new SelectList("pilih Merk"), "Pilih Merk", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlMerk", @name = "jenisBarang" })
```

The second Dropdownlist consists of some strings based on what I've chosen from the first dropdownlist.

 ex:

- a
- b
- c

When I send it to my action, it read as integer (0).

How do I get the value of the dropdownlist as a string? (ex I chose a)

edit:
this is the code to manipulate the second dropdown:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetMerk(_jenis) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#ddlMerk").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/Barang/GetMerkByJenis/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { jenisID: _jenis },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Merk</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                    markup += "<option value=" + x + ">" + data[x]+ "</option>";
                }
                $("#ddlMerk").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that used to manipulate the second dropdown?

Comment: From your dropdownlist (DDL) construction seems that you want to create cascading DDL, right? How you bind second DDL to the first one, and is that value of second DDL returned as integer instead of text?

Comment: I used javascript and ajax on how to show my data to DDL2 from DDL1, the code on js and ajax is added in the question

Comment: when you select a from DDL1, it sends an iteger or from DDL2 ?

Comment: You can see an example here: [Creating Simple Cascading DropDownList In MVC 4 Using Razor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/). Note that you need to change the second argument (`dataValueField`) with column name which represents value passed from DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your JS code, in the loop, you are binding to `select` `option`'s value your iteration variable - `x`, which is number, so it will pass integer to the controller. If you want to pass text, you should bind to `value` `data[x]` **not** `x`:

```
. . .
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    markup += "<option value=" +  data[x] + ">" + data[x]+ "</option>";
}
. . .
```

Comment: the problem is on the second dropdownlist. Whatever I chose at the second dropdownlist, it came out as integer in the model.

On the other hand, the first dropdownlist gave me string result (which is what I wanted)

Comment: How you've initialized your second DropDown list's `SelectList` with `string` parameter? There is no such overload in `SelectList`.

Comment: I was aiming to delete that parameter, but there was error when I did that, so I inserted a string there, and it actually works just find with the default option set as char-by-char ("p", "i", "l", ..., "k")

Comment: I've tried `SelectList` witch one `string` parameter, it breaks down string to chars and binds to select element. Also I haven't found any problem with that, it returns strings to controller.

Comment: I've worked my js just like you told me, and it actually works! Big thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

You are posting an integer to server. Therefore your controller received integer value for second dropdown, let's take a look at your code

```
var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Merk</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                    markup += "<option value=" + x + ">" + data[x]+ "</option>";
                }
```

If you want to get the text, it should be look like

```
var markup = "<option value=''>Select Merk</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x] + ">" + data[x]+ "</option>";
                }
```

Comment: oh yeah it works, I didn't know the integer passed because of the "option value" field. Thanks for your help Edward!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your javascript, Incase if you want to get the dropdown text in your action method
**Please replace your code with the followig**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetMerk(_jenis) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#ddlMerk").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Home/GetMerkByJenis/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { jenisID: _jenis },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Merk</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                markup += "<option value=" + data[x] + ">" + data[x] + "</option>";
            }
            $("#ddlMerk").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

}
```